# Download Javascript content

Tags: javascript, linux

Over the weekend I took part in the Ride London cycle event.  The results can be browsed at https://results.prudentialridelondon.co.uk/2019/?pid=list.  I'd really like to download all the results so I can produce some custom stats but, so far, my only option seems to be Copy/Pasting the content of 186 pages into an editor and then writing a script to manipulate it into a parsable format.  I'd appreciate some pointers on how best to parse Javascript content such as this.

Comment: Just use any of the javascript scraping library. I see that the content is served via normal HTTP responses so you could use anything. Here you have some recomendations: https://www.codementor.io/hirenpatel545/5-best-javascript-web-scraping-libraries-and-tools-sicow2rx9

Comment: You can scrap the page using any http client and then using cheerio (https://cheerio.js.org/) you can parse the html and get your data.

Comment: `parse Javascript content` - what javascript content? it's HTML

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion in this case is to use web scraping, this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by using Selenium to pull each page of the results.  As this was a one-time requirement, I didn't expend much effort making it pretty!  The grab function looked like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def grabHTML(page):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    #url = "https://results.prudentialridelondon.co.uk/2019/?page={}&event=I&event_main_group=A&num_results=100&pid=list&search%5Bsex%5D=M".format(page)
    url = "https://results.prudentialridelondon.co.uk/2019/?page={}&event=I&event_main_group=A&num_results=100&pid=list&search%5Bsex%5D=W".format(page)
    browser.get(url)
    return browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
```

I wrapped this in a simple loop to pull each page and then used Regular Expressions to pull out the fields from each row.  There's probably a much nicer way to parse the HTML but, sometimes, just good enough is good enough.  :)

Thanks for your suggestions!